# What is the best way to join two json files in angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a json file which contains the list of products.

```
[{"id":76,
  "name":"A",
  "description":"abc",
  "price":199,
  "imageUrl":"image.jpg",
  "productCategory":[{
    "categoryId":5,
    "category":null
   },{
    "categoryId":6,
    "category":null
   }
]}
```

I then have a second json file with a list of categories which look like so:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"red"},
{"id":6,"name”:"blue"}]
```

What is the best way to join the categories of this two json files in Angular? 
This is what I aim to achieve:

```
[{"id":76,
  "name":"A",
  "description":"abc",
  "price":199,
  "imageUrl":"image.jpg",
  "productCategory":[{
    "categoryId":5,
    "category":red
   },{
    "categoryId":6,
    "category":blue
   }
]}
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: like so: `"productCategory":[{
    "categoryId":5,
    "category": red
   }`

Comment: why having two category with same id and different name red and blue?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. they are 2 different categories. Im gonna fix it. But one product can have 2 categories

Comment: this product belong 2 category, why you want return only 5 red ?

Comment: I want to return all the categories. Some products have 1 category, others have 2. Sorry if I was not clear, I am still learning.

Comment: with your question, the result should be list of products?

Comment: yes. With the right category assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ex9hbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that use a service to retreive the data. Yes, the way is using switchMap and map. SwitchMap receive an array and must return an observable. with map, we transform the data received and return the data transformed

```
this.dataService.getCategories().pipe(
         //first get the categories, the categories is in the
         //variable cats
         switchMap((cats:any[])=>{
           return this.dataService.getProducts().pipe(map((res:any[])=>{
               res.forEach(p=>{ //with each product
                 p.productCategory.forEach(c=>{ //with each productCategory in product
                   //equals a propertie "category" to the propertie "name" of the cats
                   c.category=cats.find(x=>x.id==c.categoryId).name 
                 })
               })
               return res
           }))
     })).subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res)
     })
```

If only has an unique product we can make

```
this.dataService.getCategories().pipe(
         switchMap((cats:any[])=>{
           return this.dataService.getUniqProduct(2).pipe(map((res:any)=>{
                 res.productCategory.forEach(c=>{
                   c.category=cats.find(x=>x.id==c.categoryId).name
                 })
               return res
           }))
     })).subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res)
     })
```

We can improve our dataService "cached" the categories

```
  getCategories() {
    if (this.categories)
      return of(this.categories);

    return http.get(......).pipe(tap(res=>{
       this.categories=res;
    }))
  }
```

NOTE:In the stackbit I simulate the call to an http.get(...) using "of"

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function for your requirement as below

```
let products = [{
      "id": 76,
      "name": "A",
      "description": "abc",
      "price": 199,
      "imageUrl": "image.jpg",
      "productCategory": [{
        "categoryId": 2,
        "category": null
      }, {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "category": null
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 77,
      "name": "B",
      "description": "abcd",
      "price": 1997,
      "imageUrl": "image.jpg",
      "productCategory": [{
        "categoryId": 5,
        "category": null
      }, {
        "categoryId": 6,
        "category": null
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 78,
      "name": "C",
      "description": "abcde",
      "price": 1993,
      "imageUrl": "image.jpg",
      "productCategory": [{
        "categoryId": 4,
        "category": null
      }, {
        "categoryId": 6,
        "category": null
      }]
    }];


    let category = [{ "id": 5, "name": "red" }, { "id": 6, "name": "blue" }]

    let result = products.filter(p => {
      var exist = p.productCategory.filter(pc => category.find(c => c.id == pc.categoryId))[0];

      return exist;
    });

    console.log(result);
```

```js
let products = [{
      "id": 76,
      "name": "A",
      "description": "abc",
      "price": 199,
      "imageUrl": "image.jpg",
      "productCategory": [{
        "categoryId": 2,
        "category": null
      }, {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "category": null
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 77,
      "name": "B",
      "description": "abcd",
      "price": 1997,
      "imageUrl": "image.jpg",
      "productCategory": [{
        "categoryId": 5,
        "category": null
      }, {
        "categoryId": 6,
        "category": null
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 78,
      "name": "C",
      "description": "abcde",
      "price": 1993,
      "imageUrl": "image.jpg",
      "productCategory": [{
        "categoryId": 4,
        "category": null
      }, {
        "categoryId": 6,
        "category": null
      }]
    }];


    let category = [{ "id": 5, "name": "red" }, { "id": 6, "name": "blue" }]

    let result = products.filter(p => {
      var exist = p.productCategory.filter(pc => category.find(c => c.id == pc.categoryId))[0];

      return exist;
    });

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Seems to be closer to the solution but I cant understand the `let category = [{ "id": 5, "name": "red" }, { "id": 6, "name": "blue" }]`. I am using an JSON file to store the categories data. I can't write it like that because it is hardcoded. At the moment I only get an empty array

Comment: I need to connect the name too. Not only the id

Comment: where is the name in your products?